# How could I check if my memory allocation is correct?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do my own memory allocation with the `alloc` crate. The way I implemented it, and if I understand how the Layout works, the below line should get the size I want to allocate in bytes as the first argument, and a value to round to for the second. So in my example, I would like to allocate 20 bytes, which will be rounded to 4096 since I passed it that value. Then alloc will allocate that memory and return a pointer to the start of my allocation.

```rust
let pr = alloc(Layout::from_size_align(20, 4096).unwrap());
```

Is my understanding of the functionality correct? Also, is there any way to check if the number of bytes specified have been allocated or not?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is, but an alignment of 4096 is very very large. What do you mean by rounding?

Comment: rounding as in each allocation will be a multiple of 4096, depending on the input size. So in this example, 20 will be rounded to 4096 and 4096 B will be allocated, if the size was 5000, it would round to the second multiple of 4096 (8192) and 8192 B will be allocated. I think that is how it works, but I want a confirmation. Also, the size is that big because that is the default for UNIX page sizes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alignment is not about rounding the size of an allocation. Instead it has to do with the integer value of the pointer that points to the start of the allocation in the sense that this pointer must be a multiple of the alignment.

```
let pr = alloc(Layout::from_size_align(size, align).unwrap());
assert!(pr as usize % align == 0);
```

If you want to round-up the size of an allocation to the next multiple of 4096, you can do this:

```
let rounded_size = (size + 4095) / 4096;
```

If you ask for a size of 20 bytes, your allocation will only be 20 bytes large, and if you want an allocation of 4096 bytes, you should allocate 4096 bytes.

---

When choosing an alignment for your data, you should consider what types will be stored in the allocation. This is because certain types require a certain minimum alignment, e.g. an `u32` must have an alignment of at least 4.

If all you are storing in the memory is `u8` bytes, then an alignment of 1 is fine. If you need to store an `u16`, you need an alignment of 2. If you need to store an `u32` you need 4 and `u64` requires 8. If you have multiple of them, you should pick the largest alignment that one of the types require, e.g. if you store `u8`, `u32` and `u64`s in the data, pick the alignment 8.

You can compute the minimum allowed alignment for a type using [`align_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.align_of.html).

Comment: I understand now, thank you for the explanation. However, what would a good default value for align be, seeing as I don't really need to use it for my project? Or is there a different constructor for Layout that I should use (where I could pass the number of bytes only)? Haven't found anything in the docs...

Comment: @icyfox usually when allocating memory for something, you will know roughly what that *something* is. If you intend to store a struct, use `std::mem::size_of` and `std::mem::align_of` to base your layout on. Having a "default" doesn't make much sense: too low and you might not provide the alignment required, and too high you'd waste memory on alignment padding. That being said, I believe the standard `malloc` has a minimum alignment of `8`.